# How to move the menu inside the "menu border"

Tags: html, css, menu, position

As the title says, I am trying to move the menu inside the border menu. I am new to this and as they are theoretically links I thought it would be something like. a { position:absolute and then I would just choose where I would want them to go. On top of this, there is a submenu I need to move with it as well. Any ideas? THANKS! I want to move the menu to the bottom right within the border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="videos.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vines.css" />
<title>Puppy Power</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="page">
<header></header>
        <div id="dog logo">
    </div>

<ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="vines.html">Vines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Failing Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Crazy Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Funny Dogs</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">Photographs</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="hero"><h1><b>HERO</b></h1></div>


<div id="topvideo"><h1><b>TOP VIDEO</b></h1></div>

<div id="topphoto"><h1><b>TOP PHOTO</b></h1></div>

<div id="toparticles"><h1><b>TOP ARTICLE</b></h1></div>

<div id="content"><h1><b>CONTENT</b></h1></div>

<div id="footer"><h1><b>FOOTER</b></h1></div>

</body>
</html>

#page {
    max-width: 850px;
    min-width: 840px;
    min-height: 1550px;
    max-height: 1600px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



#navigation {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 813px;
    height: 187px;
    margin-left: 5px;

}



ul #navigation, .sub {
    list-style-type: none;


}

ul #navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul #navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
}

ul #navigation li:hover > a {
    background-color: #89cFF0;
}



#hero {
    width: 813px;
    height: 408px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;

}

#topvideo {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;



}

#topphoto {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

}

#toparticles {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#content {
    width: 813px;
    height: 310px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {

    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your CSS is in your selectors you keep placing #navigation where it is not supposed to go and it is breaking your CSS. For example, the rule for your li is this:

```
ul #navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

And the HTML is this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="vines.html">Vines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Failing Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Crazy Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Funny Dogs</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">Photographs</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Your CSS is trying to style a `<li>` which is a child of #navigation which is a child of `<ul>`, which there is none because the ul is #navigation. You should select it like this instead:

```
#navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

## <kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/h2YqV/8/)</kbd>

## **Updated CSS:**

```
#page {
    max-width: 850px;
    min-width: 840px;
    min-height: 1550px;
    max-height: 1600px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



#navigation {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 813px;
    height: 187px;
    margin-left: 5px;

}



#navigation , .sub {
    list-style-type: none;


}

#navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation   a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
}

#navigation   li:hover > a {
    background-color: #89cFF0;
}



#hero {
    width: 813px;
    height: 408px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;

}

#topvideo {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;



}

#topphoto {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

}

#toparticles {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#content {
    width: 813px;
    height: 310px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {

    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. The problem is it is now displacing the sub-menu, how do I make it follow it?

Comment: @BenjaminSunderland What do you mean displacing?

Comment: Sorry I found it out. .sub li

Comment: Sorry, hi there. again. The submenu is not moving when I code in .sub li . I am positioning it as absolute and trying to move it and it isn't budging. Sorry for asking again. I am trying to move the submenu as I haven't managed to include it into the "videos" when you hover over it

Comment: @BenjaminSunderland Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with all your coding you have added and post it here. i'll look at it.